# Problems with huge CPU overhead

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ado.net, dataset

I'm writing an application in vb.net 2005. The app reads a spreadsheet into a DataSet with ADO.NET and uses a column of that table to populate a ListBox. When a ListBox Item is selected, the user will be presented with detailed information on the selected record.

One part of this information isn't in the DataSet. I have to compare a column from the spreadsheet with several external data sources to determine the nature of the record in question. Here's where I have my problem.

This comparison has to search through 9.5m rows in a SQL table at one stage. I've checked and there's no way to "shrink" the query down as I'm already only searching absolutely essential data.

What happens is that the application never visibly does anything. The CPU usage shoots up to 100% regardless of what it was at beforehand and the system's performance becomes almost unbearably slow.

Can anyone suggest a way I can improve this situation while this massive query is running?

EDIT: I was originally going to write the contents of the 9.5m rows in the database table to a text file which I'd then read from, but after 6.5m rows, I got an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Could you clarify when exactly the CPU usage shoots up to 100%, ie. what is your code doing to cause it? Profiling it may help.

Comment: The CPU usage skyrockets when the application is accessing the database. I've set it to execute a SQL query filtered by the field value that I'm searching for. If any results are found, a DataSet it populated with those results, otherwise, the DataSet remains Nothing.
This is where the CPU peaks. I've left it running once or twice and it eventually throws an OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your CPU might be used in populating the `DataSet`, though you would have to profile your application to confirm that. Try using a `DataReader` instead and either storing the results in some more compact format in memory or, if you're running out of memory, then writing them to a file as you go. With the `DataReader` approach you never need to store the entire result set in memory at the same time.

Comment: CORRECT! I tried the DataReader and the results appeared on my form almost instantly. A significant improvement on the DataSet approach.
Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

1. An index in the column to search?
2. A new field in the table to help to search faster?

Comment: 1. I need to search by a specific column and I'm doing that.
2. Can you elaborate on a new field in the table to help search faster?

The database contains the company's client information and I need to go through a few approvals before I can make changes to the table schemas. Knowing my boss, I highly doubt he'll see that it's necessary.

Comment: If the search is something like Color = 'Red' you could add an integer column where you can insert, enumerated possible values of Color, or, in Oracle a bitmap index could help.

Comment: `SELECT TelephoneNumber, FirstName FROM Clients WHERE TelephoneNumber = '" & CallData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(2).ToString & "'"` is my select statement. I'm selecting by Telephone Number because that's the only information from this table that I have in the spreadsheet. The idea is that if the number in the spreadsheet appears in this table, then the call detailed in the spreadsheet was not a personal call because the call was made to a number listed on client details.